# What code in Django is it that allows Restangular.all('string').getList() to work?

Tags: angularjs, django, rest

I have the class players in my models.py. Some of these players are professional. I am able to get a list of all professional players with:

```
Restangular.all('professional').getList().then(function(data){
            $scope.segments = data;
        });
```

Why does this work? I can't find the corresponding Django code that serves this.

Some code snippets that I think might be involved but that don't really seem to match based on their names are:

- `class PlayerSerializer(ModelSerializer) in serializers.py`
- `class Player(models.Model) in models.py`

None of these indicate to me that the function `Restangular.all('professional').getList()` should work. What does `all` refer to? There are not only players in the Django model. How does Django know what to do with `professional`?

Can this wizardry be explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a question about Restangular. Looking at the documentation, declaring `Restangular.all('professional')` sets up a service that queries `/professional` on the server. DRF is presumably configured to serve something on that URL.

Comment: That explains it. There is an url pattern that serves a view to that url. That was the missing piece of the puzzle. Thank you!